# Colunas com bootstrap

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com uma dúvida quanto ao uso de colunas no bootstrap.
No meu código atual tenho o layout abaixo, porém, gostaria de colocar os quatro campos lado a lado, eu já consigo dividir em duas colunas os demais campos, mas, por uma questão estética gostaria de saber como posso proceder.
Layout atual:
[image: Layout atual]

Layout idealizado:
[image: Layout idealizado]

Segue meu código:

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!--Alinhamento de Campos-->
<input id="id_contrato" type="hidden" class="form-contratol" name="id_contrato">
<!--Primeira Coluna-->
<div class='row' align = left>
<!--Alinhamento de Campos Primeira Coluna-->
<div class='col-sm-6'>
        
<!--CNPJ-->
<!-- COLUNA CNPJ-->
<input type='hidden' id="id_contrato" name="contrato">
        
<!--Campo Situaçao-->
<label for="razao_social">Razão Social:</label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="basic-addon-razao_social"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='razao_social' id="id_razao_social" class="form-control"  autofocus required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!-- COLUNA CNPJ-->
<br>
<!--Campo NOME_FANTASIA-->
<label for="razao_fantasia">Nome Fantasia:</label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="basic-addon-nome_fantasia"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='razao_fantasia' id="id_razao_fantasia" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!--Fim Campo NOME_FANTASIA-->
<br>
<!-- COLUNA CNPJ-->
<label for="razao_social">CNPJ:</label>
<div class="input-group col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="basic-addon-cpf"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='cnpj' id="cnpj" class="form-control" autofocus placeholder='00.000.000/0000-00' required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!--Fim Campo CNPJ-->
<br>
<!--Campo CAMPO 1-->
<label for="campo1">CAMPO 1:</label>
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo1"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='campo1' id="campo1" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc' required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!--FIM Campo CAMPO 1-->
        
<!--Campo CAMPO 2-->
<label for="campo1">CAMPO 2:</label>
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo2"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='campo2' id="campo2" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc' required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!--FIM Campo CAMPO 2-->
        
<!--Campo CAMPO 3-->
<label for="campo1">CAMPO 3:</label>
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo3"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='campo3' id="campo3" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc' required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!--FIM Campo CAMPO 3-->
        
<!--Campo CAMPO 4-->
<label for="campo1">CAMPO 4:</label>
<div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo4"></span>
</div>
<input type='text' name='campo4' id="campo4" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc' required autofocus><br>
</div>
<!--FIM Campo CAMPO 4-->
        
<!--Final ROW De Posiçao Primeira Coluna-->
</div>
<!--Final ROW De Posiçao Primeira Coluna-->
<!--Fim Primeira Coluna-->
       
<!--ROW De Posiçao Segunda Coluna-->
<div class='row'>
<!--Alinhamento de Campos Segunda Coluna-->
<div class='col-sm-3 col-lg-4'>
         
<!--Fim Campo Situaçao-->
<!--Campo Data Prevista-->
         
<!--Data da Solicitaçao-->
<label for="data" class="control-label" >
<br>Data de Ativação: <br></label>
<div class="input-group col-lg-10">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
<div><input style="background-color: #008B45; color: white; text-align:center;" readonly class="form-control" type="text"
name="data" id="id_data"></div></div>
<!--Fim Data da Solicitaçao-->
          
<!--Data da Solicitaçao-->
<label for="data" class="control-label" >
<br>Data de Vencimento: <br></label>
<div class="input-group col-lg-10">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
<div><input style="background-color: #ec8a24; color: white; text-align:center;" readonly class="form-control" type="text"
name="data" id="id_data"></div></div>
<!--Fim Data da Solicitaçao--> 
           
<!--Se Houve Alteraçao no Registro Mostra a Data-->
           
           
<label for="data_alt" class="control-label" >
<br>Data de Alteração: <br></label>
<div class="input-group col-lg-10">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</div>
<div><input style="background-color: #CD2626; color: white; text-align:center;"
readonly class="form-control" type="text"
name="data_alt" id="id_data_alt"></div></div>
<!--Se Houve Alteraçao no Registro Mostra a Data-->
            
<!--Campo Observações-->
<label for="obs" class="control-label" >
<br>Observações:<br></label>
<div class="input-group">
<div class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="basic-addon-obs"></span>
</div>
<textarea name="obs" id="id_obs" style="width: 304px; height: 246px; margin: 0px;" class="form-control" placeholder="Nenhuma Observação" onkeyup="limite_obs(this)"><?php echo $obs; ?></textarea>
<script>
function limite_obs(obj) {
obj.value = obj.value.substring(0,1000);
}
</script>
</div>
<!--Fim Campo Observações-->
            
<!--Final ROW De Posiçao Segunda Coluna-->
</div>
</div>
<!--Final ROW De Posiçao Segunda Coluna-->
<!--Fim Segunda Coluna-->
</div>
```

Comment: Mas quais são os 4 campos que vc quer colocar lado a lada? E vc quer que eles fiquem lado a lado em todas as resoluções ou em telas pequenas é para ficar um abaixo do outro??

Comment: Gostaria que ficassem lado os 4 campos conforme a imagem e se possível em todas as resoluções.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente basta vc subdividir seu grid dentro da `.row`. Seu HTML tinha vários probleminhas, como alguns `<br>` desnecessário e um `.row` dentro de outra `.row` sem precisar, e além disso seu conteúdo não estava dentro de um `container` de grid. Outro problema tb é que vc colocou um valor fixo em PX para o `textarea`, mas o correto é deixar ele com 100% da largura coluna.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o grid da imagem acima

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No caso como vc quer 4 colunas em todas as resoluções vc precisa dividir seu grid em 4 colunas de 3. (4x3=12). Então ficaria `.container>.row>.col-xs-3(*4)`. Te recomendo que leia a documentação do Grid do BS3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid

Veja o código corrigido

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


  <div class="container-fluid">
    <input id="id_contrato" type="hidden" class="form-contratol" name="id_contrato">
    <!--Primeira Coluna-->
    <div class='row'>
      <!--Alinhamento de Campos Primeira Coluna-->
      <div class='col-xs-3'>

        <!--CNPJ-->
        <!-- COLUNA CNPJ-->
        <input type='hidden' id="id_contrato" name="contrato">

        <!--Campo Situaçao-->
        <label for="razao_social">Razão Social:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="basic-addon-razao_social"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='razao_social' id="id_razao_social" class="form-control" autofocus required autofocus><br>
        </div>
        <!-- COLUNA CNPJ-->
        <br>
        <!--Campo NOME_FANTASIA-->
        <label for="razao_fantasia">Nome Fantasia:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="basic-addon-nome_fantasia"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='razao_fantasia' id="id_razao_fantasia" class="form-control" required autofocus><br>
        </div>
        <!--Fim Campo NOME_FANTASIA-->
        <br>
        <!-- COLUNA CNPJ-->
        <label for="razao_social">CNPJ:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" id="basic-addon-cpf"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='cnpj' id="cnpj" class="form-control" autofocus placeholder='00.000.000/0000-00'
            required autofocus><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Fim Campo CNPJ-->
      <!-- <br> -->
      <div class='col-xs-3'>
        <!--Campo CAMPO 1-->
        <label for="campo1">CAMPO 1:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo1"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='campo1' id="campo1" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc'
            required autofocus><br>
        </div>
        <!--FIM Campo CAMPO 1-->

        <!--Campo CAMPO 2-->
        <label for="campo1">CAMPO 2:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo2"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='campo2' id="campo2" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc'
            required autofocus><br>
        </div>
        <!--FIM Campo CAMPO 2-->

        <!--Campo CAMPO 3-->
        <label for="campo1">CAMPO 3:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo3"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='campo3' id="campo3" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc'
            required autofocus><br>
        </div>
        <!--FIM Campo CAMPO 3-->

        <!--Campo CAMPO 4-->
        <label for="campo1">CAMPO 4:</label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road" id="basic-addon-campo4"></span>
          </div>
          <input type='text' name='campo4' id="campo4" class="form-control" required autofocus placeholder='Ex.: Rua, Avenida, Condomínio e etc'
            required autofocus><br>
        </div>
        <!--FIM Campo CAMPO 4-->

        <!--Final ROW De Posiçao Primeira Coluna-->
      </div>
      <!--Final ROW De Posiçao Primeira Coluna-->
      <!--Fim Primeira Coluna-->

      <!--ROW De Posiçao Segunda Coluna-->
      <div class='col-xs-3'>
        <!--Alinhamento de Campos Segunda Coluna-->
        <!-- <div class='col-sm-3 col-lg-4'> -->

        <!--Fim Campo Situaçao-->
        <!--Campo Data Prevista-->

        <!--Data da Solicitaçao-->
        <label for="data" class="control-label">
          <!-- <br> -->
          Data de Ativação:
          <br>
        </label>
        <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </div>
          <div><input style="background-color: #008B45; color: white; text-align:center;" readonly class="form-control"
              type="text" name="data" id="id_data"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Fim Data da Solicitaçao-->

        <!--Data da Solicitaçao-->
        <label for="data" class="control-label">
          <br>Data de Vencimento: <br></label>
        <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </div>
          <div><input style="background-color: #ec8a24; color: white; text-align:center;" readonly class="form-control"
              type="text" name="data" id="id_data"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Fim Data da Solicitaçao-->

        <!--Se Houve Alteraçao no Registro Mostra a Data-->


        <label for="data_alt" class="control-label">
          <br>Data de Alteração: <br></label>
        <div class="input-group col-lg-10">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </div>
          <div><input style="background-color: #CD2626; color: white; text-align:center;" readonly class="form-control"
              type="text" name="data_alt" id="id_data_alt"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Se Houve Alteraçao no Registro Mostra a Data-->
      <div class='col-xs-3'>
        <!--Campo Observações-->
        <label for="obs" class="control-label">
          <!-- <br> -->
          Observações:
          <br>
        </label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="basic-addon-obs"></span>
          </div>
          <textarea name="obs" id="id_obs" style="width: 100%; height: 246px; margin: 0px;" class="form-control"
            placeholder="Nenhuma Observação" onkeyup="limite_obs(this)"><?php echo $obs; ?></textarea>

        </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Excelente amigo! Muito bom! Ajudou pra caramba. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Esse programa que vc usou na animação é algum IDE?

Comment: @Carlos o programa mesmo onde estou mexendo no tamanho da "janela" é o próprio Chrome, usando a ferramenta do DevTools, vc primeiro aperta F12, ou Ctrl+Shift+i e clica nesse btn http://prntscr.com/n0gqbb e o programa que gravei a tela é o ScreenToGif

Comment: Valeu mesmo! Obrigado.